# Find associated matrix A of a linear transformation T

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

> Let $T$ be the linear transformation defined by 
>   $$T(x, y) :=  ( 9x+4y, x-6y, 8y, 2x-7y ).$$ 
>   *Find* its associated matrix $A$.

---

I tried $$A = \left (
\begin{matrix} 
9 & 4 \\
1 & -6 \\
0 & 8 \\
2 & -7 
\end{matrix}\right)$$

but WebWork says it is wrong and I have no clue what to do.

Comment: Welcome to Math SX! For me, it's fine.

Comment: Your answer is correct.

Comment: I guess all you can do is let WebWork know it's wrong since you've got it right.

Answer (score 1):

You want an $A$ matrix that lives in $M(4,2,\mathbb{R})$ the space of the matrices with four rows, two columns and real entries,  such that, for a given $T:\mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R^4}$, defined as above, you'll get

$$T(\vec{x}) = A\vec{x}$$

Let $\vec{x} := \left(\begin{matrix}x\\y\end{matrix}\right)$, then if you use the $A$ defined above in your question you will get

$$A\vec{x} = \left (
\begin{matrix} 
9 & 4 \\
1 & -6 \\
0 & 8 \\
2 & -7 
\end{matrix}\right) \cdot \left(\begin{matrix}x\\y\end{matrix}\right) =\left (
\begin{matrix} 
9x+ 4y \\
1x -6y \\
0x+ 8y \\
2x -7y 
\end{matrix}\right) = T(\vec{x})$$

So the $A$ given is the correct one.